# Issues on using R's "rgl" and "car" for 3D scatter plot and multiple regression

Tags: r, 3d, visualization, rgl

I am working on plotting a scatter plot of three variables and a multiple regression with two covariates using R's "rgl" and "car" package.

I have three issues:

1. I can't change the background color from black to white.
2. I can't rotate objects without the image becoming messy.
3. When running the code for the multiple regression plot, several errors show up, despite using code from a tutorial on the subject (link below).

For 1 and 2 I have tried:

```
rgl.open()
rgl.bg(color = "white")
rgl.points(x, y, z, color = "blue", size = 5) # Scatter plot
```

and:

```
bg3d("white")
scatter3d(x = x, y = y, z = z)
scatter3d(x = x, y = y, z = z,
          point.col = "blue", surface=FALSE)
```

In both cases I get this result:

[image]

and when rotating:

[image]

For 3, I have used the following code (from [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/a-complete-guide-to-3d-visualization-device-system-in-r-r-software-and-data-visualization#regression-plane)) which returns two errors:

```
>rgl_init()
**Error in rgl_init() : could not find function "rgl_init"**
> rgl.spheres(x, y, z, r = 0.2, color = "#D95F02") 
> rgl_add_axes(x, y, z, show.bbox = FALSE)
**Error in rgl_add_axes(x, y, z, show.bbox = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "rgl_add_axes"**
> aspect3d(1,1,1)
> # Compute the linear regression (y = ax + bz + d)
> fit <- lm(y ~ x + z)
> # predict values on regular xz grid
> grid.lines = 12
> x.pred <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = grid.lines)
> z.pred <- seq(min(z), max(z), length.out = grid.lines)
> xz <- expand.grid( x = x.pred, z = z.pred)
> y.pred <- matrix(predict(fit, newdata = xz), 
+                  nrow = grid.lines, ncol = grid.lines)
> # Add regression surface
> rgl.surface(x.pred, z.pred, y.pred, color = "steelblue", 
+             alpha = 0.5, lit = FALSE)  
> # Add grid lines
> rgl.surface(x.pred, z.pred, y.pred, color = "black",
+             alpha = 0.5, lit = FALSE, front = "lines", back = "lines")
```

Comment: That web page gives really bad advice.  Use the documentation from the package instead.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I tried following the documentation in the package. I still get a black background. I will keep working on this as there seems to be something that needs to be specified.

Comment: You should show us what you did.  The package docs don't talk about `rgl_init`, and recommend against using `rgl.spheres`.